# how can i get rtsp link data in browser with webassembly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rust, rtsp, webassembly

I work with rust-wasm and I want to get RTSP link data with std::net,
but I have an invalid port error with TcpStream

```
#![allow(unused)]
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::net::TcpStream;

fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let mut stream = TcpStream::connect("rtsp://user:pass@192.168.2.206:554/Streaming/Channels/101")?;

    stream.write(&[1])?;
    stream.read(&mut [0; 128])?;
    Ok(())
} // the stream is closed here
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Could you add which is the error that you are getting?

Comment: `TcpStream::connect` doesn't take a full URL, but only a (server, port) combination (which may be a string like `"192.168.2.206:554"`). You will need to handle the authentication and path yourself or use one of the [available `rtsp` crates](https://crates.io/search?page=1&per_page=10&q=rtsp&sort=relevance) to handle that part.

Comment: hi, thanks for your comments,
I see the RTSP crates but which one is the best library for my project?